# Added slash in href

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm woundering how it's possible, this is my code:

```
echo '<span class="store_url">'.JText::_('WEB').': <a href="'.$item->store_url.'" target="_blank">'.$item->store_url.'</a></span>';
```

And in the output I get:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/www.website.com">www.website.com</a>
```

In href and link are the same values: $item->store_url
How it's possible in href there is extra "/"?
It's joomla site, and I have standard joomla .htaaccess, but added redirection from http to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if I delete it all: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] there is still "/"

Comment: You should probably first figure out why `$item->store_url` is missing the scheme.

Comment: if I do above echo $item->store_url, I get www.website.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is Joomla or some plugin for it? In your Joomla control panel or plugin configuration, you can set the URL to your own site. You have probably entered `www.website.com` there. You should actually have entered `http://www.website.com`. Joomla or the plugin uses that value to build internal links in the website.

The problem you have is that browsers see URL `www.website.com` as a **relative path** to the current page's path. If it was `http://www.website.com/`, browsers would have seen it as an **absolute path**.

The page where the browser has found this link is in the root of the domain. Probably `http://www.website.com/` itsself or `http://www.website.com/something.php`. So the browser himself adds the leading `/` to the relative URL, to indicate the path is relative to the root of the domain. (You are seeing the `/` in the **rendered HTML Source**, as interpreted by the browser. Just look in the **original HTML Source**, you will not find a leading `/` there.)

Linking relatively from `http://www.website.com/` to `/www.website.com` will end up at `http://www.website.com/www.website.com`.

In closing: the lesson here is, when installing and configuring some 3rd party software, always pay very close attention to the settings you are setting. And when possible consult the manual!